# C# Constructing immutable objects with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, closures, immutability, factory-pattern

I am trying to design a factory class that will make it easy for people on my team to add new "actions", I want the properties of the class to be immutable but for debugging purposes I the delegates need to be able to reference properties on the containing class.

Consider the following class:

```
public class NamedAction
{
    public NamedAction(string name, Action action)
    {
        // Here there is some additional validation, 
        // such as null parameter checking, etc.
        Name = name;
        Action = action;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Action Action { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return "Action: " + Name;
    }
}
```

In a factory class I have the following method to create an instance of a special named action:

```
private static NamedAction GetSpecialAction()
{
    NamedAction na = null;
    na = new NamedAction(
        "SpecialAction",
        () => {
            Console.WriteLine("My name is " + na.Name + " and I am special");
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, its " + na.Name + " again. I like kittens.");
        }
    );
    return na;
}
```

The problem I have with this is that ReSharper is telling that the second Console.WriteLine is accessing a modified closure. I guess its because the captured variable is actually still "null" when its reference is captured in the construction of the delegate because it is a parameter to the constructor.

To enforce correct usage I want to guarantee that the Action is not null and is immutable, and so far I haven't found any way to do it without a constructor. I thought about using a builder pattern but I don't see how you could provide access to "self" (this) in side the assigned actions, I'm wary about telling my team to ignore the modified closure warning.

I have an idea where I people could create blueprint/objects which are then sent to a builder/assembler class returning a concrete object but that really doesn't solve my problem of guaranteeing non-null at compile time.

Before giving up I was hoping there was some elegant solution to my problem...

Comment: I can't see the connection between constraint of having a not null `Action` and the code you are providing. You can easily check in the constructor the passed parameters to make sure they are "ok". If you are passing a delegate like you are doing, it's up to developer to not create a action like that

Comment: Yes I guess, an earlier version I wrote had a single param ctor (name) and the Action property had a public setter so that it could be assigned after construction. (No "modified closure" warnings) A  flaw is that someone might forget to set it and create a named action that does nothing but does not throw an exception when used ( as I check for null in the class that manages NamedAction instances).

I could make an "assign once" setter.

Comment: (Ignore comment above I accidentally posted somehow by pressing enter...)

What I don't want is devs doing bad things like replacing the delegate inside the delegate. I could make an "assign once" setter which would keep it from going out of hand but it would not be obvious that re-assignment has no effect.

Another flaw is that someone might forget to set it, but I can check for null in the class that handles the instances. Seems there is no way to make incorrect usage hard, as in coding it in such a way that the compiler complains.

Comment: Well, you could make it as parameter of the constructor. In case its null, throw an exception. Although the check will not reveal a `null` prameter when compiling. But this way, it is not possible to create a `NamedAction` without an action during runtime. If there is no need to expose the `Action`, dont't do it.